# ECMAscript 6: watch changes to class properties

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, watch

Let's say I have a class defined as follows:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor (a) {
        this.a = a;     
    }

    _onPropertyChanged() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Whenever the property "a" of an instance of MyClass changes, I want to trigger the _onPropertyChanged method on that instance.
What is the best (most performant) way to achieve this using ECMAscript 6?

Comment: use a getter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you need to watch all properties, or just a fixed one?

Comment: "most performant" --- "performance" is not the absolute property of a system. Multiple implementations in a given environment can be compared though.

Comment: Assignments to `a` can be easily tracked with accessor methods, as the answer shows. If you want to track if values differ, etc, the question will automatically fall into 'too broad' category. Performant change detection is a complex task that all modern JS frameworks have to solve. Don't expect that their experience can be explained in a single answer.

Comment: Check out [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: @naomik thanks for pointing out about Proxy. It seems a bit overkill for what I need, but it is a very interesting topic for example in case you need custom data binding without using 3rd part libraries/frameworks. I'll check it out!

Comment: @revy You should keep in mind that Proxy is *not* performant. It's quite slow.

Comment: @estus Ok, thank you for the warning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 'best' way, and the actual approach always depends on the final goal.

In its simplistic (and performant enough) form it is:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor (a) {
      this.a = a;     
    }

    get a() {
      return this._a;
    }

    set a(val) {
      this._a = val;
      this._onPropertyChanged('a', val);
    }

    _onPropertyChanged(propName, val) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo in constructor: missing underscore.

Comment: @cartant This is not a typo. Constructor changes `a` property, and the onPropertyChanged hook is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what you can do for this situation and for a single property.

```
class MyClass {

constructor (a) {
    this._a = a;
}

set a(value) {
    let hasChanged = (this._a !== value);
    this._a = value;
    //Assumes value is primitive. Customize for objects
    if(hasChanged) this._onPropertyChanged();

}

_onPropertyChanged() {
    // do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to define a setter and a getter for the property like the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43461361/7842231) said. However, it won't work if you already have a defined setter.

Another way is a non-standard Object.prototype.watch, which only works natively in Gecko. If you want to bring its support to most other browsers, you can use a small but powerful [Andrea Giammarchi's library](https://github.com/WebReflection/wrist).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is redefine filed/property, but in this case u have some pit falls, like 'find owner of this prop'. U can use [this](https://github.com/anetegithub/geranium/blob/master/geranium/runtime/reflection/Property.ts) solution for totally-safe property redefining.

The main idea is redefine property if exists:

```
 Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
     get() { return get(ownPropertyDescriptor.get.call(target)); },
     set(val) {
         let _val = set.call(this, val);
         if (_val != undefined)
            ownPropertyDescriptor.set.call(target, _val);
         },
     configurable: true
 });
```

Or create new property based on `symbol` type:

```
var indexer = Symbol(name);
target[indexer] = target[name];
Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
  get() {
         var val = target[indexer];
         var _val = get(val);
           return _val;
     },
  set(val) {
         let _val = set.call(this, val);
         arget[indexer] = set(_val);
     },
  configurable: true
});
```

[Full method is part of complex solution for property-redefining.](https://github.com/anetegithub/geranium/blob/master/geranium/runtime/reflection/Property.ts)